# Gunicorn: No module named '/path/to/my/django/project'

Tags: gunicorn, wsgi, systemd

I was using gunicorn with nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 system to deploy a django project and want to create a systemd service for gunicorn. In `/lib/systemd/system/gunicorn-mywebsite.service`, I write following codes:

```
ExecStart=/home/myusername/sites/pythonEnv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/mywebsite.socket /path/to/my/django/project.wsgi:application
```

But when I ran `service gunicorn-mywebsite start`, there was problem `No module named '/path/to/my/django/project'`.

If I run the same command my django project directory with relative path of my wsgi:application, it will work.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't give gunicorn a path to a file, it needs to be a module path, with application entry point name. So just `project.wsgi:application`. If the directory containing `project` is not in your path, then use the `--pythonpath` to gunicorn to tell it where it is.